The least number of five digits which when divided by $18$ and $24$ leaves $5$ and $11$ respectively as remainders.
The problem:

Find the least number of five digits which when divided by $18$ and $24$
leaves $5$ and $11$ respectively as remainders.

Let denote the number with $n$, we have:
$$n=18k+5\Rightarrow 4n=72k+20$$
$$n=24k'+11\Rightarrow 3n=72k'+33$$
So, $n=72(k-k')-13$, and the smallest number is:
$$7200+4\times720-13=10067$$I'm wondering if my answer is right.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Yes it's correct. Another way is to see that $$n=72a-13$$ where $a=k'-k$
Now when $a=140$ is the smallest $a$ for which we get $n$ as a five digit number, and consequently we will have $n=10067$

Please do not answer off-topic SV questions,

@BillDubuque will keep that in mind
